# Toggle div up or down based on class of nav that was changed by jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a nav that turns sticky when the user scrolls it to top done by adding a class with jQuery. Now I need to check that class on hover so that my dropdown nav that went up, will now go down.

this is my sticky nav jquery

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
 var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = $('#page').offset().top,
    fromtop      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

    if ( fromtop <= 30 ) {
        // Your div has reached the top
        $('.main-navigation').removeClass('main-nav-pos');
        $('.main-navigation').addClass('main-nav-fixed');
        $('.nav-bottom').css({"display":"none"});
    } else {
        $('.main-navigation').removeClass('main-nav-fixed');
        $('.main-navigation').addClass('main-nav-pos');
        $('.nav-bottom').css({"display":"block"});
    }

});
```

This is my nav dropdown:

```
$('.main-navigation li a').hover(

function() {
            //display dropdown
            $(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"height":"100%"}, 100);
            $(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"top":"-105%"}, 'fast');
            $(this).children('.butterfly').css({"display":"block"}, 'slow');
        },

        function() {
            //hide dropdown
            $(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"height":"0"}, 100);
            $(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"top":"0%"}, 'fast');
            $(this).children('.butterfly').css({"display":"none"}, 'slow');
        }
);
```

Everytime i try to wrap the above in an if/else, to check for the "main-nav-pos" class, it gets real buggy.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can you be more specific with 'buggy'?  does it go in and out fast?

Comment: @briansol - like, if I wrap it in a on hover .hasclass, it doesn't work. If i include it wrapped in the onScroll it jumps all over the place everytime i touch the mousewheel.

Comment: **Just FYI** You should really cache your selectors and use jquery chaining.  `var $main=$('.main-navigation'); $main.addClass('main-nav-pos').removeClass('main-nav-fixed');`  etc.

Comment: The scroll event is going to fire a lot, which sounds like it may be too much for what you want to do with it.   So, you need to throttle it.   There are plugins for this.  Google "jquery debounce" and look for Ben Alman's plugin, it should help you to reduce the crazy firing.

Comment: Thanks, @GaryStorey - learned something new. I still can't seem to figure out the on hover, look for the class that was added from the on scroll function. It just wants to apply whatever was there first.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with the necessary JS/CSS/HTML?  http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @GaryStorey, absolutely. Let me know if you want me to simplify or tidy it up. http://jsfiddle.net/acrane/h5pcgfsx/25/

Comment: @GaryStorey, you'll notice that classes get added to 2 things, just not the "nav-info" once you scroll to top then scroll back down. Thanks!

Comment: Check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/h5pcgfsx/37/  If you like it, then I will post as an answer.

Comment: @GaryStorey, so when you scroll back down and the nav becomes unfixed again, the dropdown still goes down, and it should go up with it being unfixed. the class to the nav-info is getting applied only the first time, and not when you scroll back down for some reason.

Comment: @acrane Not sure I follow.  You have two animations. Does one only go when its fixed and the other goes when it isnt?

Comment: @GaryStorey, at first the main-nav is in the middle of the page and the hover drops a menu "up", if you scroll so that the main-nav becomes fixed at the top, the "nav-info"(the dropdown) changes classes to "nav-info-fixed" and drops "down" - just like i want it to. The problem I have is if you scroll back down, "nav-info-fixed" doens't change back to it's original class and therefor continues to drop down instead of up. I forked it and made it easier to see what's going on with a black bg.  http://jsfiddle.net/acrane/84oxssau/

Comment: OK.  I think I have it about figured out... I will post something tomorrow

Comment: The classes and everything are getting applied correctly when you scroll.  I think the problem lies in that both animations are being applied on hover for the same elements.  Maybe use the `off()` method to remove the existing hover event when the menu becomes fixed and add the new animation.  Do the same thing in reverse when it becomes positioned again.

Comment: @GaryStorey, I really appreciate all your help on this. After another look with fresh eyes, I noticed that I had a navinfo var, but not a navinfo-fixed. So i was trying to remove something that was not there. So, now I wrapped my hover functions in a if/else, and have it working but it is verrry slow to "do it's thing". So I guess I'll start another question on optimizing the function as it really doesn't relate to this question. Thanks.

Comment: @acrane Awesome! I did a lot of optimizations on the fiddle I was playing with for this.  When you get the new question posted let me know and I will post.